# Jersey Namebinding technique in Spring Boot Rest

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jersey, name-binding

I have seen the name binding strategy from jersey to shield the api, it's pretty cool for authentication, and it's pretty cool to just annotate the endpoints you want to authenticate, and in jersey you can bind the annotation to the filter.

does anybody knows how to achieve this in spring boot ?

Comment: Spring Boot isn't tied to any REST framework. It is simply a bootstrapping framework. You can use Jersey with Spring Boot just as you can use Spring MVC with Spring Boot. Are you actually asking about _Spring MVC_?

Comment: I know i can use jersey in spring boot, but you know there some bootstrapped stuff by default, using jersey adds complexity to my project, like registering stuff, i want to save that using spring boot web for rest, that's why i'm asking if i can achieve this without jersey ;)

Comment: My point is that Spring Boot is not a rest framework, Spring _MVC_ is. Are you talking about Spring MVC?

Comment: Well yes, that is what spring boot uses behind, so, yes

Comment: With Spring MVC, you can use the `HandlerInterceptor` and use the `HandlerMethod` to get the `Method` and check the `Method` for an annotation. I'm not sure if there is a way to just annotate the method to determine if the interceptor should be called for that method or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Check maven dependencies**
Check the maven file should have spring-boot-starter-jersey dependency in it.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Create REST APIs**

Now create some JAX-RS resources which we will access into testing phase. I have created `UserResource` class.

**UserResource.java**

```
package com.howtodoinjava.jerseydemo;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "users")
@Path("/users")
public class UserResource 
{
    private static Map<Integer, User> DB = new HashMap<>(); 

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Users getAllUsers() {
        Users users = new Users();
        users.setUsers(new ArrayList<>(DB.values()));
        return users;
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response createUser(User user) throws URISyntaxException 
    {
        if(user.getFirstName() == null || user.getLastName() == null) {
            return Response.status(400).entity("Please provide all mandatory inputs").build();
        }
        user.setId(DB.values().size()+1);
        user.setUri("/user-management/"+user.getId());
        DB.put(user.getId(), user);
        return Response.status(201).contentLocation(new URI(user.getUri())).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response getUserById(@PathParam("id") int id) throws URISyntaxException 
    {
        User user = DB.get(id);
        if(user == null) {
            return Response.status(404).build();
        }
        return Response
                .status(200)
                .entity(user)
                .contentLocation(new URI("/user-management/"+id)).build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response updateUser(@PathParam("id") int id, User user) throws URISyntaxException 
    {
        User temp = DB.get(id);
        if(user == null) {
            return Response.status(404).build();
        }
        temp.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
        temp.setLastName(user.getLastName());
        DB.put(temp.getId(), temp);
        return Response.status(200).entity(temp).build();
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Response deleteUser(@PathParam("id") int id) throws URISyntaxException {
        User user = DB.get(id);
        if(user != null) {
            DB.remove(user.getId());
            return Response.status(200).build();
        }
        return Response.status(404).build();
    }

    static
    {
        User user1 = new User();
        user1.setId(1);
        user1.setFirstName("John");
        user1.setLastName("Wick");
        user1.setUri("/user-management/1");

        User user2 = new User();
        user2.setId(2);
        user2.setFirstName("Harry");
        user2.setLastName("Potter");
        user2.setUri("/user-management/2");

        DB.put(user1.getId(), user1);
        DB.put(user2.getId(), user2);
    }
}
```

**Users.java**

```
package com.howtodoinjava.jerseydemo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @XmlAttribute(name="uri")
    private String uri;

    @XmlElement(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @XmlElement(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**Configure Jersey**

Now we have a JAX-RS resource and we want to access it from spring boot application which include Jersey dependency. Let’s register this resource as Jersey resource.

package com.howtodoinjava.jerseydemo;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

```
@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig 
{
    public JerseyConfig() 
    {
        register(SecurityFilter.class);
        register(UserResource.class);
    }
}
```

- Look at the `@Component` annotation. It enables this class to be
  registered while spring boot auto scans the java classes in source
  folder.
- `ResourceConfig` provides advanced capabilities to simplify
  registration of JAX-RS components.
- `SecurityFilter` class is the actual auth details processor which we
  will see later in this tutorial.

> Extend spring boot application with SpringBootServletInitializer.

```
package com.howtodoinjava.jerseydemo;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class JerseydemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new JerseydemoApplication().configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(JerseydemoApplication.class)).run(args);
    }
}
```

**Secure REST APIs with JAX-RS Annotations**

Now when our APIs are ready, we will start securing them. Let’s annotate the APIs with **JAX-RS annotations** based on their desired access level and user roles allowed to access them.

```
package com.howtodoinjava.jerseydemo;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "users")
@Path("/users")
public class UserResource 
{
    private static Map<Integer, User> DB = new HashMap<>(); 

    @GET
    @PermitAll
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Users getAllUsers() {
        Users users = new Users();
        users.setUsers(new ArrayList<>(DB.values()));
        return users;
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
    public Response createUser(User user) throws URISyntaxException 
    {
        if(user.getFirstName() == null || user.getLastName() == null) {
            return Response.status(400).entity("Please provide all mandatory inputs").build();
        }
        user.setId(DB.values().size()+1);
        user.setUri("/user-management/"+user.getId());
        DB.put(user.getId(), user);
        return Response.status(201).contentLocation(new URI(user.getUri())).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @PermitAll
    public Response getUserById(@PathParam("id") int id) throws URISyntaxException 
    {
        User user = DB.get(id);
        if(user == null) {
            return Response.status(404).build();
        }
        return Response
                .status(200)
                .entity(user)
                .contentLocation(new URI("/user-management/"+id)).build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
    public Response updateUser(@PathParam("id") int id, User user) throws URISyntaxException 
    {
        User temp = DB.get(id);
        if(user == null) {
            return Response.status(404).build();
        }
        temp.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
        temp.setLastName(user.getLastName());
        DB.put(temp.getId(), temp);
        return Response.status(200).entity(temp).build();
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{id}")
    @RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
    public Response deleteUser(@PathParam("id") int id) throws URISyntaxException {
        User user = DB.get(id);
        if(user != null) {
            DB.remove(user.getId());
            return Response.status(200).build();
        }
        return Response.status(404).build();
    }

    static
    {
        User user1 = new User();
        user1.setId(1);
        user1.setFirstName("John");
        user1.setLastName("Wick");
        user1.setUri("/user-management/1");

        User user2 = new User();
        user2.setId(2);
        user2.setFirstName("Harry");
        user2.setLastName("Potter");
        user2.setUri("/user-management/2");

        DB.put(user1.getId(), user1);
        DB.put(user2.getId(), user2);
    }
}
```

> You can see the security related JAX-RS annotations in above
>   highlighted lines.

**Write security filter using JAX-RS ContainerRequestFilter**

---

Now it’s time to write our security filter which will examine the incoming requests, fetch the authorization information (basic auth in this example), and then will match user name and password, and finally it will verify the user’s access level by it’s role. If everything matches, API will be accessed else user will get access denied response.

```
package com.howtodoinjava.jerseydemo;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.annotation.security.DenyAll;
import javax.annotation.security.PermitAll;
import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

/**
 * This filter verify the access permissions for a user based on 
 * user name and password provided in request
 * */
@Provider
public class SecurityFilter implements javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter
{
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_PROPERTY = "Authorization";
    private static final String AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME = "Basic";
    private static final Response ACCESS_DENIED = Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
    private static final Response ACCESS_FORBIDDEN = Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).build();
    private static final Response SERVER_ERROR = Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
    {
        Method method = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
        //Access allowed for all 
        if( ! method.isAnnotationPresent(PermitAll.class))
        {
            //Access denied for all 
            if(method.isAnnotationPresent(DenyAll.class))
            {
                requestContext.abortWith(ACCESS_FORBIDDEN);
                return;
            }

            //Get request headers
            final MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = requestContext.getHeaders();

            //Fetch authorization header
            final List<String> authorization = headers.get(AUTHORIZATION_PROPERTY);

            //If no authorization information present; block access
            if(authorization == null || authorization.isEmpty())
            {
                requestContext.abortWith(ACCESS_DENIED);
                return;
            }

            //Get encoded username and password
            final String encodedUserPassword = authorization.get(0).replaceFirst(AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME + " ", "");

            //Decode username and password
            String usernameAndPassword = null;
            try {
                usernameAndPassword = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedUserPassword));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                requestContext.abortWith(SERVER_ERROR);
                return;
            }

            //Split username and password tokens
            final StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(usernameAndPassword, ":");
            final String username = tokenizer.nextToken();
            final String password = tokenizer.nextToken();

            //Verifying Username and password
            if(!(username.equalsIgnoreCase("admin") && password.equalsIgnoreCase("password"))){
                requestContext.abortWith(ACCESS_DENIED);
                return;
            }

            //Verify user access
            if(method.isAnnotationPresent(RolesAllowed.class))
            {
                RolesAllowed rolesAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(RolesAllowed.class);
                Set<String> rolesSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(rolesAnnotation.value()));

                //Is user valid?
                if( ! isUserAllowed(username, password, rolesSet))
                {
                    requestContext.abortWith(ACCESS_DENIED);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private boolean isUserAllowed(final String username, final String password, final Set<String> rolesSet) 
    {
        boolean isAllowed = false;

        //Step 1. Fetch password from database and match with password in argument
        //If both match then get the defined role for user from database and continue; else return isAllowed [false]
        //Access the database and do this part yourself
        //String userRole = userMgr.getUserRole(username);
        String userRole = "ADMIN";

        //Step 2. Verify user role
        if(rolesSet.contains(userRole))
        {
            isAllowed = true;
        }
        return isAllowed;
    }
}
```